# How to get a probability distribution from a function

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

let us suppose we have a function between [a,b], and we want to transform this function into a probability distribution.
The main point is that the integral between [a,b] is equal to 1. How can I rescale the function in order to get this? I didn't find any formula to do this.

Comment: If $C:=\int f<\infty$ and $f>0$ everywhere then $h(x)=f(x)/C$ is a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Just normalize the function: compute its $L^1$ norm and then define the probability distribution as the original function divided by that ($\tilde{f} := f/||f||_1$, provided the function is integrable).

N.B. In order to be a density it also has to be positive, not only with unitary integral.

Comment: Yeah, I had to be more specific in the question about my problem I will open another question. Thanks